# In DTD, what's the difference between <!ELEMENT channel (rating?)*> and <!ELEMENT channel (rating)*>

Tags: xml, dtd

I am reading this: [ttp://emacspeak.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/rss-0.91.dtd](http://emacspeak.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/rss-0.91.dtd):

```
<!ELEMENT rss (channel)>
<!ATTLIST rss
version     CDATA #REQUIRED> <!-- must be "0.91"> -->
<!ELEMENT channel (title | description | link | language | item+ | rating? | image? | textinput? | copyright? | pubDate? | lastBuildDate? | docs? | managingEditor? | webMaster? | skipHours? | skipDays?)*>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT link (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (title | url | link | width? | height? | description?)*>
<!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT item (title | link | description)*>
<!ELEMENT textinput (title | description | name | link)*>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rating (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT width (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT copyright (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pubDate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastBuildDate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT docs (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT managingEditor (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT webMaster (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hour (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT skipHours (hour+)>
<!ELEMENT skipDays (day+)>
```

In the forth line, I wander why `item` is followed with a `+`, and why `rating` is followed by a `?`? Why those recurrence operators are needed, and what do they mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there's no practical difference. With a choice of elements where elements of that choice can occur an arbitrary number of times (`(…|…|…)*`) there's no point in annotating any cardinality constraints on any of the members. Zero or more times round of one or more things is exactly the same as zero or more. Zero or more times round of one or zero things is exactly the same as zero or more.

It would be different if a sequence (`(…,…,…)`) were being used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help you: [DTD Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp)

Basically:

> The + sign declares that the child element
>   "message" must occur one or more times inside the element.

And

> The ? sign declares that the child element
>   "message" can occur zero or one time inside the element.

Observe the difference from **must** and **can** from each qupte

Comment: I know that, but they are followed by `*`, then why `+` or `?` is needed.

Comment: Maybe the comment from the rss 2.0 dtd will make you understand. It's really not that is not correct from a technical point of view. It's just how they have declared the dtd elements. But for the rss example they say this: `A channel can apparently either have one or more items, 
     or just a title, link, and description of its own`. Basically, you need to have item regardless of the other elements (i.e. `+`), but the other elements are not mandatory. Maybe it's not the perfect dtd declaration, but it's the way it is

Answer (score 1):

`(X+|Y?)*` is equivalent to `(X|Y)*`. The operators in your example DTD are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

- `+` means *one or more*
- `?` means *zero or one*

Comment: I know that, but they are followed by `*`, then why `+` or `?` is needed.